# NextAuth token undefined using Axios Interceptors

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, next-auth

I am using NextAuth and Axios interceptor for login API.  The session works perfectly. I tried to check in the console, and I get the token. However, when I check the Authorization header, the bearer token is undefined. Here is my solution so far.

This is my [...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth, { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import axios from 'src/lib/axios'

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      
     async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials

        const res = await axios.post(`/login`, {
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        const user = res.data

        if (user) {
          return user
        } else {
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      return { ...token, ...user, ...account }
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user = token

      return session
    }
  }
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

    export const axiosAuth = axios.create({
      baseURL: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api`,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json, multipart/form-data'
      }
})
```

useAxios.js

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { axiosAuth } from './axios'

const useAxiosAuth = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestIntercept = axiosAuth.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      if (!config.headers['Authorization']) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${session?.user.token}`
      }

      return config
    })

    return () => {
      axiosAuth.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept)
    }
  }, [session?.user.token])

  return axiosAuth
}

export default useAxiosAuth
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue?